# MVC5 jquery ajax autocomplete could not be loaded from page refrencing _layout

Tags: layout, asp.net-mvc-5, bundle, jquery-ui-autocomplete

I have a MVC5 project.
in a simple page I've written a jquery autocomplete search for companies search
it's working with simple page in project with this source:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="~/Content/css/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/bootstrap.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var comid = 0;
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $("#inputlg").autocomplete({                
                source: function (request, response) {
                    $.ajax({
                        url: "/Companies/Search",
                        type: "POST",
                        dataType: "json",
                        data: { name: request.term },
                        success: function (data) {
                            response($.map(data, function (item) {                                 
                                comid=item.CompanyId;
                                return { label: item.CompanyName, value: item.CompanyName };                                
                                var companyid = item.CompanyId;
                                return $(@Html.ActionLink(companyname, "Ratings2", "Companies", new { id = companyid }, null));*@                                
                            }))
                        }
                    })
                },
                messages: {
                    noResults: "", results: ""
                },
                select: function (event, ui)
                {                                        
                    window.location.href = "Ratings2/"+comid;
                }
            });
        })
    </script>
```

It's working. 
But in main page which has layout as parent get jquery TypeError: $(...).autocomplete is not a function
I have bundleconfig.cs like this:

```
public static void RegisterBundles(BundleCollection bundles)
        {
            BundleTable.EnableOptimizations = false;
            bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jquery").Include(
                        "~/Scripts/jquery-{version}.js"
                        ));

            bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jquery-ui").Include(
                        "~/Scripts/jquery-ui.js"));

            bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/feature").Include(
                        "~/Scripts/feature/js/*.js"));

            bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jqueryval").Include(
                        "~/Scripts/jquery.validate*"));

            // Use the development version of Modernizr to develop with and learn from. Then, when you're
            // ready for production, use the build tool at https://modernizr.com to pick only the tests you need.
            bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/modernizr").Include(
                        "~/Scripts/modernizr-*"));

            bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/bootstrap").Include(
                      "~/Scripts/bootstrap.js",
                      "~/Scripts/respond.js",
                      "~/Scripts/bootstrap-3.3.0.min.js",
                      "~/Scripts/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"));

            bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/Content/css").Include(
                      "~/Content/bootstrap.css",
                      "~/Content/site.css",
                      "~/Content/style.css",
                      "~/Content/font-awesome.css",
                      "~/Content/Crauseltrustpilot.css",
                      "~/Content/login.css",
                      "~/Content/sliderbar.css",
                      "~/Content/rating.css",//,
                      //"~/Content/bootstrap-3.3.0.min.css"  
                      "~/Content/css/mdb.css",
                      "~/Content/css/mdb.min.css",
                      "~/Content/css/style.css",
                      "~/Content/css/style.min.css",
                      "~/Content/css/addons/datatables.css",
                      "~/Content/css/addons/datatables.min.css",
                      "~/Content/font.css"
                      ));

            bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/Content/boot").Include(                     
                      "~/Content/bootstrap-3.3.0.min.css"
                      ));
        }
```

and my main page code is like this:

```
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery-ui")

    <!-- Bootstrap core JavaScript
    ================================================== -->        
    <!-- Placed at the end of the document so the pages load faster -->
    @*<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">*@
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/Content/css/jquery-ui.css">
    @*<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>*@
    @*<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>*@    
    @*<script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>*@  
    @*<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-ui.js"></script>*@  
    @*<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>*@
    @*<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>*@
    <script src="~/Scripts/bootstrap.js"></script>   
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var comid = 0;
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $("#inputlg").autocomplete({
                source: function (request, response) {
                    $.ajax({
                        url: "/Companies/Search",
                        type: "POST",
                        dataType: "json",
                        data: { name: request.term },
                        success: function (data) {
                            response($.map(data, function (item) {
                                //return { label: item.CompanyName, value: item.CompanyName };
                                comid = item.CompanyId;
                                return { label: item.CompanyName, value: item.CompanyName };
                                //return { a: "https://localhost:44379/Companies/Ratings2/" + item.CompanyId, value: item.CompanyName };
                                //////////////////////
                                @*var companyname = item.CompanyName;
                                var companyid = item.CompanyId;
                                return $(@Html.ActionLink(companyname, "Ratings2", "Companies", new { id = companyid }, null));*@                                                                   
                            }))
        }
                    })
                },
        messages: {
            noResults: "", results: ""
        },
        select: function (event, ui) {
            window.location.href = "Ratings2/" + comid;
        }
            });
        })
    </script>
```

If you looked at main page, I've tested other ways that refrencing from bunlde.

Comment: One thing you need to do is remove `"~/Scripts/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"` from your `~/bundles/bootstrap` (that is including a 2nd copy of jquery and would be wiping out all prior scripts that rely on jquery

Comment: @StephenMuecke that error is gone, but I get this error: TypeError: elem.getClientRects is not a function[Learn More]  jquery-3.3.1.js:10020:9 ???

Comment: @StephenMuecke I've added breakpoint to my js code, from this line to end it is not executed: return { label: item.CompanyName, value: item.CompanyName };

Comment: @StephenMuecke    messages: and select: breakpoint wont hit

Comment: @StephenMuecke Sorry for asking lots of question. Do you have any suggestions about the new error?

Comment: @StephenMuecke please add your answer outside comment, which I could make it as answered. Thank you

Comment: Did you sort out the other error? (I have not had a chance to look at that yet)

Comment: @StephenMuecke Yes,Thank you.first error solved based on your answer. and second one done based on another search ☺

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a `ScriptBundle` for `"jquery"` which includes `jquery-{version}.js` and then another `ScriptBundle` for `"bootstrap"` which includes `jquery-1.11.1.min.js`, so if the bootstrap bundle is loaded after the jquery-ui bundle, it effectively wipes out `jquery-ui` (because it relies on jquery being loaded before).

Remove the jquery script from the `"bootstrap"` bundle

```
bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/bootstrap").Include(
    "~/Scripts/bootstrap.js",
    "~/Scripts/respond.js",
    "~/Scripts/bootstrap-3.3.0.min.js"));
```

As a side note, include the full versions of scripts in your bundles, not the `min` versions. In debug mode, the full versions will be loaded (making it easier to debug them), and in production, they will be automatically minified by the framework.